# Width and height is not working in kivy app for android

Tags: python, kivy, apk, kivymd, buildozer

when I run my code it's getting arranged properly in pc as per window however I resize but when I make it an app using buildozer it's not getting arranged as it's not able to access root.height and root.width.

help me find how I can get width and height of the screen in mobile or android device.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label

Builder.load_string("""
<LoginScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        name: 'login_p'
        cols:1
        FloatLayout:
            size: root.width, root.height/2
            Label:
                text: "Login to your Account"
                size_hint: 0.8, 0.25
                pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "top":1}
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            Label:
                size_hint: 0.5,0.12
                pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.8}
                text: "Username : "
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            TextInput:
                pos_hint: {"x":0.4, "top":0.8}
                size_hint: 0.5, 0.12
                id: namee
                multiline: False
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            Label:
                size_hint: 0.5,0.12
                pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.8-0.13}
                text: "Password : "
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            TextInput:
                pos_hint: {"x":0.4, "top":0.8-0.13}
                size_hint: 0.5, 0.12
                id: password
                multiline: False
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.2,"y":0.35}
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.1
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 17**4
            text: "Already have an Account? Log In"
""")

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass    

class mainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(LoginScreen(name='login'))
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainApp().run()
```